# How can I perform a search for a form feed character in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, unicode, find-and-replace, symbols

I'm sorting out a document for someone that downloaded huge land ownership files for counties in a city.  It was initially in CSV format.  I realized that certain files had an unidentified character in the data that was causing problems with fundamental operations like sort, even after converting to .xlsx.  Weirdly, if I selected all the columns with data in them, it would omit the last column from the sort criteria, instead placing a blank column in the front.

Using the UNICODE function I determined it was the form feed character as it was designated 12, and that seems to match up.  I found a couple ways to remove the character.  First was selecting the data and manually deleting it.  Since there were so many I was able to use the REPLACE function to delete the first character where it appeared.

My only problem now is finding any other instances of this form feed in a tab with 300,000 rows.  It can be selected, but copy and pasting it into Find & Replace doesn't work, it doesn't even put a blank space in there.  Any suggestions?
[image: Form Feed]

Comment: Instead of `REPLACE`, have you considered `SUBSTITUTE`?

Comment: Thanks, that did help.